# Turn off floats temporally

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, minipage, height

I have written a command which puts content into a minipage to measures its height. It uses this information to insert "intelligent" pagebreaks, newpages, clearpages and warnings.

To do the measuring the content has to be put into a box, I guess this is unavoidable. Floats are forbidden.

I want this command to be applicable on everything. I dont want to measure the height of any float. That would make no sense as I dont know where they will be in the end. Most properly they will appear somewhere later in the document and will not influence the desired pagebreaking-behaviour.

So this is my Problem: I need to turn off all floats when measuring. Floats should be ignored.

This example shows what I want to do:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\newlength{\fooLength}%
\newsavebox{\fooBox}%

\newcommand{\fooCmd}[1]{%
%measure
%\TurnFloatsOFF (I need this)
\savebox{\fooBox}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}}%
%\TurnFloatsON (I need this)
\settototalheight\fooLength{\usebox{\fooBox}}%
%do stuff
\ifdim\fooLength>3\baselineskip%
    \newpage#1%
\else% 
    #1%
\fi%
}%

\begin{document}
\blindtext%
\fooCmd{\blindtext}%no problem
%\fooCmd{\begin{figure}\blindtext\end{figure}}%does not work
\end{document}
```

I have not yet found anything usefull. Maybe the comments-package can do the trick. It offers the following:

```
\excludecomment{figure}
```

This did not work though. Also, I need to deactivate all floats, not just the figures. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Floats cannot be inside a `minipage` in general anyway, so why not just put them outside the argument of `\fooCmd` rather than inside?

Answer (score 2):

Note that this will almost certainly result is much *less* intelligent page breaks than (La)TeX would give you left to its own devices. The best approach to page breaking is *not to touch it* until the document is in its final form and then, if necessary, tweak it manually to the least extent possible.

That is, ***don't try this at home!***

The is, to say the least, extremely crude.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\newlength{\foolength}%
\newsavebox{\foobox}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foocmd}[1]{%
%measure
%\TurnFloatsOFF (I need this)
\begingroup
\renewenvironment{figure}{\@gobble}{\relax}%
\renewenvironment{table}{\@gobble}{\relax}%
\renewcommand\caption[1]{\relax}%
\savebox{\foobox}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}}%
\settototalheight\foolength{\usebox{\foobox}}%
% \TurnFloatsON (I need this)
% do stuff
\ifdim\foolength>3\baselineskip%
  \endgroup
    \newpage#1%
\else%
  \endgroup
    #1%
\fi%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blindtext%

\foocmd{\blindtext\blindtext}% no problem

\foocmd{\begin{figure}\blindtext\caption{A figure}\end{figure}}% also works

\foocmd{\blindtext\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image: unintelligent page breaking]